# Reading Tables From OracleDB Using Camel

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

Hi I am new to Service mix.Can anyone pointing me in right direction how to read the tables from  oracle Db  and post that table into a local files.(Here i want to use only blueprint.XML content which i can directly deploy in service mix deploy folder).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
public class JdbcReadFromOracleRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("sql:select full_name from common.company where code='1'?delay=3000&dataSource=oracleDataSource&outputType=SelectOne")
                .routeId("testOracleRead").autoStartup(true)
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "JDBC oracle : ${body}");
        .to("file://c:/test/test.txt")
    }
}
```

And you can use pax-jdbc (https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/spaces/PAXJDBC/overview) to create datasource (https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXJDBC/Oracle+driver+adapter).

Once you got the table's record, you can create the file contents using the template engine (e.g. **velocity** (http://camel.apache.org/velocity.html)) or otherwise and then save the file by the component **file** (http://camel.apache.org/file2.html).

Comment: Thanx so much Alexey for your quick response.... can we use only blueprint.xml file alone? or camel is the only approach? can you please explain me in detail? Just now started to use servicemix by using blueprint

Comment: Yes you can use only blueprint.xml... you can just translate Java DSL to Blueprint XML (http://camel.apache.org/dsl.html). You can try to depelop some examples, or test, like here (http://camel.apache.org/using-osgi-blueprint-with-camel.html)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use [Camel's SQL Component](http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html).

```
   <route id="foo">
       <from uri="sql:select * from foo"/>
   </route>
```

The returned data will be an List of Maps in the Exchange Body that you can then easily iterate through using [Camel's Splitter EIP](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) as the next step after the database select:

```
<split>
   <simple>${body}</simple>
</split>
```

There are a number of ways you could build your file within the `<split>`.  Individual field values can be accessed using `simple` with `${body[FIELD_NAME_HERE]}`

However keep in mind that the exchange is new for each split iteration, so you can't assemble your file contents in anything within the exchange, like a header or property. Instead, I'd probably use an aggregation strategy with the split, known as a [Composed Message Processor](http://camel.apache.org/composed-message-processor.html).  That way you can build your file in any format you want, row by row, within the old exchange body.  Then after the `</split>` end, simply use [Camel's File component](http://camel.apache.org/file.html) to save the exchange body to a file.

Another option is to execute a Processor after your SQL statement, and the List of Maps in the exchange body will be available to your Java code to iterate through and build your file if you're more comfortable doing it that way. Camel's splitter also has overhead, so if performance is an issue and you're processing thousands of records, this may be the best option.

Comment: Thanx so much Gerry for your quick response.. I am very new to service mix so can you able to post any detailed code please? i am using service mix with blueprint.xml

Comment: You can find a full working example in the Maven Repository [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-example-sql-blueprint/2.19.1). If you prefer, the example is also on [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-sql-blueprint).  I also recommend you get your hands on the book Camel in Action.  I don't think I could have managed without it.